# añadir en un método de una subclase, la propiedad de otra subclase

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente código de la subclase Dog y Fish que heredan de Animal, estas son las propiedades y métodos de las clases.

```
Class Animal {
    constructor(name,height,weight){
        
        this.name=name;
        this.height=height;
        this.weight=weight;
    }
    nameLength(){
        return this.name.length;
    }
}
class Dog extends Animal{
    constructor(name,height,weight,barkVolume,leashColor, speed) {
        super(name,height,weight);  //to have access to all properties and methods in animal class
        this.barkVolume= barkVolume;
        this.leashColor=leashColor;
        this.speed=speed;
    }
    bark(){
        if(this.barkVolume > 50){
            console.log(this.name, "barks loudly volume:", this.barkVolume);
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.name, "barks timidly volume:", this.barkVolume);
        }
    }
}

class Fish extends Animal {

    constructor(name,height,weight,swimSpeed){
        super(name,height,weight);
        this.swimSpeed=swimSpeed;
    }
    swim(chaserSpeed){
        if(this.swimSpeed > 50){
            console.log(this.name, "swims around quickly, speed:", this.swimSpeed)
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.name, "swims around slowly, speed:", this.swimSpeed)
        }
        if(this.swimSpeed > chaserSpeed){
            console.log( this.name, "got away with speed of:", this.swimSpeed  )
        }
        else{
            console.log(this.name, " did not get away because speed of the chaser is:", //¿Dog.speed?//);
        }
    }
}
```

mi pregunta viene en el método de la clase Fish, el método `swim()` ¿Es posible que yo cree un perro que tenga una velocidad mayor que el fish y que figure la velocidad del perro que la tengo definida en la subclase Dog como speed, este situada en el método swim() de la clase Fish, indicando la velocidad del perro, aunque esta propiedad no forme parte de la clase Fish?quedando algo así como:

```
else{
    console.log(this.name, " did not get away because speed of the chaser is:", //¿Dog.speed?//);
}
```

Si creo una variable de Dog por ejemplo:

```
var pluto = new Dog("Pluto", 12, 45, 15, "red", 52);
```

entonces podría poner su velocidad solo para este perro en concreto en el método swim() tal que así:

```
else{
            console.log(this.name, " did not get away because speed of the chaser is:", pluto.speed);
        }
```

pero claro me gustaría que fuese para cualquier perro. ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: La verdad que no me queda del todo claro, pero si la idea es imprimir la velocidad del perro cuando se llama al método `swim` de un pez, entonces seria tan simple como poner `chaserSpeed` en el `console.log`. Ejemplo: `fish.swim(dog.speed)`.

Comment: @Marcos me refiero a imprimir la velocidad del perro dentro del método swim() de la clase fish en el último else